# Ui Not updating when property updated in codebehind

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I want to update my datagrid cell when i change property in code Behind. My code is
    Model (Entity)

```
public partial class IGdaily
{
    public int GDaily_Id { get; set; }
    public int Item_Id { get; set; }
}
```

View model

```
  public class Vm_Purchase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    IGoldEntities db = new IGoldEntities();
    //public ObservableCollection<IGdaily> Vm_IGdaily { get; set; }

    public IGdaily Obj_IGdaily { get; set; }
    public Vm_Purchase()
    {
        Obj_IGdaily = new IGdaily();
    }
    public Int32 Item_Id
    {
        get { return Obj_IGdaily.Item_Id; }
        set
        {
            Obj_IGdaily.Item_Id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Item_Id");
        }
    }
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
 }
```

In Xaml

```
 <iG:DataGridTextcolumn Binding="{Binding Item_Id, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Item Id" Width="SizeToHeader"  />
```

In Main Window

```
 Vm_Purchase ItmId = new Vm_Purchase();
 ItmId.Item_Id = Id;
```

Here I want to change Id in code, My problem is grid cell is not updating. please help me my problem. Can I use ObservableCollection to acheive this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The given codes are incomplete, I can't figure out what the problem is. What's the ItemsSource of the `DataGrid` control? And how does it bind to the `DataGrid` control?

The following code may be what you are looking for:

```
public partial class IGdaily : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _gDailyId;
    private int _itemId;

    public int GDaily_Id
    {
        get { return _gDailyId; }
        set
        {
            _gDailyId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Item_Id
    {
        get { return _itemId; }
        set
        {
            _itemId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In Main Window

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<IGdaily> Vm_IGdaily { get; } = new ObservableCollection<IGdaily>();
    private IGdaily testData = new IGdaily();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TheDataGridControl.ItemsSource = Vm_IGdaily;
        Vm_IGdaily.Add(testData);
    }

    private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        testData.GDaily_Id = 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: I use IGdaily as datagrid binding (ItemsSource="{Binding IGdaily}" )

Comment: `ItemsSource` should be a collection.